# Can't load requests module to Kivy iOS app

Tags: python, ios, python-requests, kivy

When I try to load the requests module into my Python code with

```
import requests
```

and then build the Kivy app using the toolchain, it crashes on in the iOS simulator. (I am developing on macOS.)

I have used

```
kivy -m pip install requests
```

which appears to install requests into the Kivy virtualenv, but it still crashes the iOS simulator.

I have even tried copying the requests library itself and placing it in my project as a subdirectory. In this instance it will run correctly in macOS but still crash in the iOS simulator.

When I say "it crashes", what I mean is that the simulator tries to open the app, then closes it after showing a black screen for about one second. If I do not include the "import requests" line, the app opens fine and goes to the correct initial screen. Here are the Xcode logs from the simulator run:

```
2016-10-28 22:25:57.433587 mentat[9488:154501] bundleid: org.kivy.mentat, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.442428 mentat[9488:154501] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.486633 mentat[9488:154643] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.516511 mentat[9488:154643] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.535126 mentat[9488:154640] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.592160 mentat[9488:154501] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.594924 mentat[9488:154501] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.794404 mentat[9488:154501] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: Workspace, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-10-28 22:25:57.796 mentat[9488:154501] Available orientation: KIVY_ORIENTATION=LandscapeLeft LandscapeRight Portrait PortraitUpsideDown
2016-10-28 22:25:57.797 mentat[9488:154501] PythonHome is: /Users/matt/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/529262BC-AA42-4190-8212-77C1D2723BA7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F52EAFF5-5458-4121-A7A9-749796FB82AF/mentat.app
2016-10-28 22:25:57.798 mentat[9488:154501] Initializing python
2016-10-28 22:25:57.955 mentat[9488:154501] Running main.pyo: /Users/matt/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/529262BC-AA42-4190-8212-77C1D2723BA7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F52EAFF5-5458-4121-A7A9-749796FB82AF/mentat.app/YourApp/main.pyo
2016-10-28 22:25:57.999 mentat[9488:154501] Application quit abnormally!
2016-10-28 22:25:58.004 mentat[9488:154501] Leaving
```

I don't find the messages to be informative. Perhaps there is a logging option I can turn on?

Comment: Please describe what happens when it crashes, with specific error messages or log snippets if possible.

Comment: I have added the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that the current version of `requests` (2.11.1) doesn't work with iOS, or at least not with Kivy-iOS. Manually cloning `requests2.9.1` and putting it in my project directory solved the problem.